# How to get solutions of this book?

Tags: problem-solving, online-resources

I am reading the book, "Lemmas in Olympiad Geometry".This book has a nice collection of problems at the end of almost every chapter but unfortunately, there is no solution given to it. Now I am helplessly trying to solve these problems but unable to solve many of them. Even if I ask for a solution in MSE, It is getting downvotes.

Let alone solving those problems, I am unable to make any approach to some of those. How can I get hints or solutions to these problems?

Comment: Problems are for you to solve. If you just read the solutions without trying to solve them, that would not be of much use (at least while preparing for Olympiads). So I suggest you to try solving the problems first. And if you can't solve, you can post them  on MSE with including your efforts. Then you won't be downvoted.

Comment: Have you tried hanging out at the Art of Problem Solving forums?

Comment: @littleO,Yes, I tried they didn't solve difficult problems.

Comment: I think the above comment is correct -- show what you tried and where you got stuck, and you probably won't get downvoted --  but you could also consider just using different resources, perhaps, such as the Art of Problem Solving textbooks.